# Solving a complicated equation system

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get a value in a web application, using some informations. I succeeded on creating this system (I need $x$):

$

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{matrix} 
x & = & \dot a + b - c - (\dot d \cdot \dot e)\\
b & = & f \cdot \dot g\\
f & = & \frac{x - \dot d - h}{1 + \dot i}\\
c & = & \dot \alpha(b)\\
h & = & x \cdot \dot e
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{equation}

$

But it seems I can't solve it. Please, note that I know the value of the dotted variables (like $\dot p$).

My fear is that I can't solve this system. If so, is there a way to approximate the value of $x$?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

*Edit*: I added two equations. I don't know it this can help, anyway I added them. Note that I know the value of $\alpha()$, but I did not put that here because it does not contain any of the variables of the system. It's there as a placeholder for an if statement.

Comment: With given values for the dotted variables, this is a *linear* system for $x$, $b$, $c$, $f$, $h$, so it's a routine matter to solve it, but it's underdetermined since you have 5 unknowns but only 3 equations. This means that you can't expect a unique solution.

Comment: I added two equations. I don't know if that can help, anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know $\alpha(b)$ (I don't see it dotted) you still have six unknowns and five equations. If you do know $\alpha(b)$ you have a linear system.  If you insert $x=he$ for $x$ in the third equation, then substitute all the rest into the first you have

$x=a+\frac{x-d-he}{1+i}-\alpha(b)-de$

$x\left(1-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=x\frac{i}{1+i}=a+\frac{-d-he}{1+i}-\alpha(b)-de$

$x=\frac{i+1}{i}(a-\alpha(b)-de)-i(d+he)$

Comment: Yes, I know the value of $\alpha(b)$. Thank you!